# Why can I not correct a typo

Tags: discussion, support

I want to correct a typo ("file contents"=>"filecontents") in [How to add adsurl field as link to bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286742/95516), but when I try to do so I see the message:

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

But since there is nothing else to improve this restrictions is bad and should be removed!!!

Comment: May be you could leave a comment below the answer like in addition to the comment you made already. I want to inform you a typo in code " \end{file contents} -->  \end{filecontents}". So it would be corrected by the person who posted the answer.

Comment: Lower-reputation users are limited to making larger edits. I'll make the change here.

Comment: Aha. Thank you. But maybe this limitation is generally not so useful.

Comment: @FrankBreitling: It is useful, as lower-rep users tend to revel in the +2 suggested edit bonus they receive from an approved edit (up to +1,000). So they tend to go crazy for it. Editing a post also bumps it to the front page, making menial (small) edits give (possibly older) posts an unnecessary boost of attention.

Comment: @Werner: And why would one care about the rep?

Comment: @FrankBreitling: [Some do](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3545/5764), or at least have in the past. It's a lure that some don't care about, but others crave like rep-crack. :-o

Comment: Then why not limit the carving instead? For example limit the number of small corrections per day or reduce the points with every correction on the same day.